# Mixing image resolutions in Cocos2d-x 3.0

Tags: android, ios, image, cocos2d-x

I download high resolution images to my Cocos2d-x iOS/Android app. The medium and low resolution images are bundled with the app. Devices that want to use high res images start with medium res images and then use high res once all the high res images have been downloaded.

So the current set-up is either/or: either use all medium res images or all high res images, but never a mixture.

Can Cocos2d-x 3.0 run with a mixture of medium and high res images at the same time?

Comment: you would have to hack ccfileutils to look for downloaded textures first, but generally that would work - however be sure you have the users agree to download the hd textures

Comment: Ok, modifying the file utils shouldn't be an issue. Why do users need to agree to download the high res images? This is only for devices that want high res images (and would have them bundled otherwise).

Comment: Because no one likes apps that consume their precious bandwidth without asking. Many, many mobile users have data plans that cover only 100 to 1000 mb per month, and once used up, these users are locked to a 64 kbit/s connection or have to pay for more bandwidth.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D good point, thanks. Just curious: would the bundled high res images use about the same amount of bandwidth when bundled w/ the app vs downloaded later? Also, I think the "only download high res images to devices that can use them" is a win in terms of consuming user bandwidth effectively. With this approach, low + med res devices never have to download the high res assets (before they did since the high res assets were bundled).